# What is the Cassandra CQL equivalent for INCR (increment a CounterColumn)?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

What is the CQL equivalent for this:
INCR MyCounter['123']['test'] BY 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the CQL syntax reference here: [Cassandra Query Language (CQL) v2.0](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#UpdatingCounterColumns). To increment a counter in CQL:

```
update MyCounter set test = test + 1 where KEY = '123';
```